# Show GBoard number pad as default in android with option to switch to alphabetic keyboard in bottom left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-keypad, gboard

I am trying to set the google keyboard **number keypad** as default but so far no luck.
Below is the image where number pad also has an option to switch to **ABC Keypad**. Normally, when we want only characters or number then in **inputType** of **editText** we can set accordingly but how to set this kind of numeric keypad as default when user clicks on editText field. Also should be able to switch to ABC keypad.

[image]

Comment: Could you post some of the code of what you've tried to do to show the numeric pad?

Comment: I was trying methods of edittext such as setInputType and setRawInputType that didn't help me.